# Shape is not working properly for circular property in flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter

I'm trying to make a circular image box, but after using `shape: Boxshape.circle`, it is working properly on my current image. I'm sure that the `shape` property doesn't depend on the image pixel or any sort of thing.

I have this code:

```
return Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 40.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 144.0,
              width: 144.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  image: AssetImage('MY_IMAGE')
                )
              )
            )
          ]
        )
      )
    ],
);
```

I have read about the `Boxdecoration` from this link: [Flutter - BoxDecoration](https://medium.com/jlouage/flutter-boxdecoration-cheat-sheet-72cedaa1ba20). I'm confident that the `shape` should work but in my case, it is not working.

This is the result which I'm getting right now:

[image: Resultant Image]

Answer (score 2):

Use a `ClipRRect` inside a `SizedBox` :

```
  Container(
    child: new SizedBox(
                height: 144.0,
                width: 144.0,
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(72.0),
                  child: new Image.asset('MY_IMAGE'),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but I'm afraid to tell you that it is not working for me. Getting the same result just a little bit of radius curves. I have changed the radius to `100`, same result. Changed it to `200` & `300` also but same result.

Comment: Change the `fit` property of your original code to `BoxFit.contain` https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html

Comment: Hey, I have edited the code. I guess some container is restricting it to come like this, cos I have read more links and they have the same code as me, but they are getting the results. **Your suggestion for BoxFit.contain** is not working out either.

Comment: The most probable reason your image is not clipped properly is that its width doesn't match its height. To confirm this point use an `image` with typical width and height and see the result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
Container(
          color: Colors.amber,// this is just for detection, rounded or not
          child: Center(
            child: new Container(
                height: 144.0,
                width: 144.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(72),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        image: AssetImage('assets/img1.png')))),
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same code that you have posted in the question. But, instead of `BoxFit.contain` or `BoxFit.fill`, try using `BoxFit.cover`.

As it is mentioned in the comment by **Mazin Ibrahim** in the above answer, the actual height of your image must be less than the radius of the circular container, so even though the container is circular in shape you are not able to see it.

Check [this link](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works using ClipOval in the child, and increasing a bit the image size with Transform.scale

```
                 Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40))),
                    child: ClipOval(
                      child: Transform.scale(
                        scale: 1.6,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          "my asset image",
                          width: 80,
                          height: 80,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case it worked like that -

```
 Container(
          height: (20.0),
          width: (20.0),
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
          child: ClipOval(
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/icons/$icon.svg',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              color: color,
            ),
          ),
    )
```